# What kind of thermometer do I use to check dryer temperature? Can same one be used to check stove temperature?

Tags: repair, dryer, appliances, stove

Is there a thermometer that can be used to check dryer temperature, and if so, what kind should be used?  Should only a multimeter be used on the dryer's thermostat instead?  I'm just wanting to doublecheck that a dryer is heating to proper temperature.  I would like to know if there is one that can be used both on a dryer and a stove, like maybe a thermometer that is just used for appliance repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect people repairing appliances either use

- a k-type thermocouple attached to a suitable multimeter.
- a thermometer specific to the type of appliance.

The key factors are probably temperature range, accuracy and the mechanical details.

Comment: Please clarify for me if you know if there is a thermometer specific to testing dryer temperature, and if so, what it would be called.  Also, would the k-type thermocouple work on both the stove and dryer?